# How to evaluate the Sine Series (Taylor) for value of x using Recursion in C?

Tags: c

(C) calculate series

> y = x - <sup>x<sup>3</sup></sup>/<sub>3!</sub> + <sup>x<sup>5</sup></sup>/<sub>5!</sub> - <sup>x<sup>7</sup></sup>/<sub>7!</sub> + .....

where stopping criterion is

> | <sup>x<sup>i</sup></sup>/<sub>i!</sub> | <= 0.001

What I have tried :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int fact(int x){
    if(x>1){
        return x * fact(x-1);
    }
    else {
        return 1 ;
    }
}

int main () {
    int x , i=1 , sign=1 ;
    float result ;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    while(abs(pow(x,i)/fact(i))>0.001){
        result += sign*(pow(x,i)/fact(i));
        i+2;
        sign = sign * -1 ;
    }
    printf("result= %f\n",result);
    return 0 ;
}
```

the problem is 
when i input 90 ... the output should be 1 ... ( it's like the sin(x) ) 
im getting a different output

Comment: And what's the problem? What's the question?

Comment: when i input 90 ... the output should be 1 ... ( it's like the sin(x) )

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: `i+2;` does nothing. Maybe you meant to do `i+=2;`?

Comment: @CoolGuy: And the compiler should have wanred about this.

Comment: @CoolGuy thanks :D ,, but still the output is wrong

Comment: Are you sure? you need to convert the values to radians, and this being a taylor series expansion the value will not be exact not even ideally exact, and when you take into account the round off issues with floating point operations then you will hardly be close to the value...

Comment: You *cannot* input 90. Taylor's expansion takes **radians** as `x`.

Comment: @shauryachats not taylor expansion, `sin()` would naturally take radians, humans use degrees because it's easier to visualize 90 degress when it's not so obvious when you say `pi/2` radians.

Comment: Aside from errors that are keeping it from working at all, having a `fact` function is a horribly bad and inefficient design. Think of how you would do this on paper. When you're computing `9!` would you go all the way back to the beginning and multiply `1*2*3*4*...`?

Comment: Please do not edit your question when answers/comments had been given already. This might make the answer ununderstandable. Therefore I undid the change from `i+2` to `i = i + 2`.

Comment: the output that im getting is strange it's 49086088.000000 , i want to fixed it :D .... sin(90 degrees) should be 1 or sin(90 radians) should be 0.89399 .... what im getting is 49086088.000000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is very clear. You have to convert degree into radian before performing the loop. Your code has some other issues also.

Here is the rectified code, which gives you 1 for 90:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int fact(int x){
    if(x>1){
        return x * fact(x-1);
    }
    else {
        return 1 ;
    }
}

int main () {
    int x , i=1 , sign=1;
    double result, rad;
    scanf("%d",&x);
    rad = x/180.0*3.1415;
    while((pow(x,i)/fact(i))>0.001){
        result += sign*(pow(rad,i)/fact(i));
        i+=2;
        sign *= -1 ;
    }
    printf("result= %f\n",result);
    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Why are you calculating the next power and factorial when you have the previous. `Un = -U(n-1) * x * x / (n * 2 * (n * 2 + 1)` - You need to double check that.

Comment: Actually we have to use  `while((pow(rad,i)/fact(i))>0.001)` but it gives 0.999... for  it.

Comment: why u removed the fabs() ? ... the formula of the sin x says we have to use fabs( pow(rad,i)/fact(i) ) <= 0.001 as a stopping condition not just pow(rad,i)/fact(i) ... when i use fabs() the program crashes i don't know why ... is that why u removed fabs ?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. We need `fabs()`, which I ignored because it seems not necessary while running the program; and it leads to improper working too. The reason for its improper working lies on the problem of comparison of floating-point numbers. See this article: http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.htm

Comment: @EdHeal, yes, that is an important point. I didn't think about it because the code had to be simpler. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

The code (at least) misses to initialise `result`.

Change

```
float result;
```

to

```
float result = 0.f;
```

---

Also

```
i+2;
```

is a NOP (no-operation). It results in nothing. It adds `2` to `i` and does not assign the result to anything, "throughs away" the result.

To increment `i` by `2` do:

```
i = i + 2;
```

or

```
i += 2;
```

---

Also^2 using `abs()` won't work as it return `int`.

Use `fabs()` to get a floating point value.

Or just do not use it at all as it's argument will never be negative here.

---

As a final advice prefer using `double` over `float`, as `float`s accurary is limited.

Comment: Why the dot in `float result = 0.;`?

Comment: For completeness, I initialise a `float` with a floating point literal. @CoolGuy

Comment: it's not necessary to initialize result , its zero by default

Comment: Because it's good practice I would even do it `float result = 0.f;`.

Comment: @Mhmoudko: It's not. It would only be initialised if either declared `static` or be defined gloablly .. or by bad luck.

Comment: @Mhmoudko I am sorry but you are totally wrong, if you declare it `static float result;` it would be different. But there is no such thing as **zero by default**, in c if a variable is not initialized it's value is undefined, using it causes undefined behavior obviously.

Comment: ok , thanks u so much , let's back to the problem ,,,
sin(90) must be 1 ,, im getting 49086088.000000

Answer (score 0):

```
sin(90)=0.89399666360055789051826949840421...
```

Besides the unit confusion, your code is not very efficient, as you compute the powers and factorials from scratch on each term, when a nice recurrence exists.

```
Sin= x
Term= x
Factor= -x*x
i= 2
while |Term| > 0.001:
    Term*= Factor / (i * (i+1))
    Sin+= Term
    i+= 2
```

Because of huge cancellation errors, this formula is not appropriate for large values of the argument. My own implementation gives `-1.07524337969e+21` for `90`.

If you compute it for `90-14*2*Pi` instead, you get `0.893995...`, not a so bad result.

Comment: the output that im getting is strange . it's 49086088.000000 , i want to fixed it :D

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm that calculates sin (x) using the following power series: sin (x) = (x / 1!) - (X ^ 3/3) + (x ^ 5/5!) - (! ^ x 7/7) + ... We stop the calculation when the difference between two succesive terms of the sum given is less than a certain tolerance.